# Can I win a culture victory after I win a science victory?

Tags: civilization-5

I won a science victory but was aiming for a culture victory. I'm one civ away from a culture victory. Is it possible to win more than one victory in an offline civ 5 game?

Comment: How do you accidentally assemble a spaceship?

Answer (score 7):

Nope, once you win, you can elect to keep playing via "Just one more turn...", but you cannot Win a second time.

In the future, you may consider disabling victory conditions during game setup if you are attempting to win in particular ways for achievements or the like.

Comment: @lalex Rather than starting over, you may want to look in the game's autosaves and find one from before you completed the Science victory and simply not complete the Science victory, since it's a victory condition you have to trigger manually to achieve.